# Looking for an elegant way for looping simultaneously over two list with different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking for the most elegant/short/pythonic way to iterate through two uneven lists simultaneously. If the shorter list ends at some point, it should start to iterate from the beginning.

So far, I managed to do it with the `while`, which I consider as ugly, and too long (from various reasons I need as short code as possible).

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

i1 = 0
i2 = 0
while True:
    if i2 == len(list2):
        break
    if i1 == len(list1):
        i1 = 0
    print(list1[i1], list2[i2])
    i1 += 1
    i2 += 1
```

The expected result should look like this. I'm achieving it with while loop (the code above). But I need to have as short code as possible:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
a 4
b 5
c 6
a 7
b 8
c 9
a 10
```

Comment: itertools.cycle

Comment: Look into `itertools.cycle` from the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).  This is right up the alley.

Comment: Not that it's really relevant.. I did a test on the m 3 highest voted answers and seems @Hoog's performs best on average. This is neglegable and irrelevant but for those that wanted to know without doing the tests, see https://repl.it/repls/NiceRosyAddons for my test and update if I'm off. Pluse it looks the cleanest imo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`zip` both lists, feeding the shortest one to [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) so it repeats indefinitely (until `list2` ends):

```
import itertools

list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for a,b in zip(itertools.cycle(list1),list2):
    print(a,b)
```

prints:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
a 4
b 5
c 6
a 7
b 8
c 9
a 10
```

(of course don't use `itertools.zip_longest` as `cycle` never ends, which would create an infinite loop)

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

for i, e in enumerate(list2):
    print(list1[i % len(list1)], e)
```

**Output**

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
a 4
b 5
c 6
a 7
b 8
c 9
a 10
```

Comment: Clever, this does not require any additional import

Answer (score 4):

I've got something that is a bit cleaner than what you've got and doesn't require you know in advance which is larger.  No idea if this is the most elegant/short/pythonic way to do things but here goes:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

length1 = len(list1)
length2 = len(list2)

for i in range(max(length1,length2)):
    print(list1[i%length1],list2[i%length2])
```

prints the following:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
a 4
b 5
c 6
a 7
b 8
c 9
a 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the sizes of your lists, use `sorted` to get it:

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

shorter, longer = sorted([list1, list2], key=len)
```

Now you can `itertools.cycle` the shorter one, and `zip`:

```
for item1, item2 in zip(cycle(shorter), longer):
    ...
```

This won't necessarily print your items in the order that you may have originally wanted (`list1` on the left, `list2` on the right). To fix that, you can just compute the longer list by hand:

```
iter1, iter2 = cycle(list1), list2 if len(list1) < len(list2) else list1, cycle(list2)
for item1, item2 in zip(iter1, iter2):
    ...
```

You could make it a one-liner with

```
for item1, item2 in zip(*(cycle(list1), list2 if len(list1) < len(list2) else list1, cycle(list2))):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print(list(itertools.cycle(list1), list2))
```

Comment: The question is tagged Python-3.x

Comment: Oh. You're right. Of course just `zip(itertools.cycle(list1), list))`